# Is this a suitable question? "Can you solve this existential problem for me?"

Tags: discussion, questions

Is this a suitable question for this SE?

> ### Can you solve this existential problem for me?
>
> Being moral is so easy (about as difficult as hitting capslock) that it seems pointless, yet most people (whatever that means) seem to find it very difficult, so that immoralism for anyone else is *also* worthless. And yet, I want for almost nothing, and am not in love. Neither do I have any talent for art, or really anything at all.

Comment: Is the question: *should this situation be presented as a question on PSE?*

Comment: could it in some form, yes @FrankHubeny

Comment: I don't see a question here, nor a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the question would be closed because it is too broad and primarily opinion-based, however, I can see why it is an important question. Because of that it could be a motivator for *many* questions that could be asked here. Each of those questions would be very specific giving someone else an opportunity to provide a brief answer.

To find more specific questions to ask, pick some tags of interest all motivated by this underlying question. Read the questions and answers under those tags, mark some as favorites and up-vote others. Some references in those posts may seem interesting. Read those references. When something puzzles you about what you have read, make a note suggesting a possible question you could ask later citing the source. You may even find while reading some questions that you can answer them. Answer them. Writing that answer may suggest to you another potential question.

From your notes of possible questions find a question you might ask that you are most interested in. Post the question. Accept the best answer if any. If you do not get at least one net up-vote think about how better to phrase your next question. Repeat the process posting no more than one question per day.

How will that process help answer the original question that might be too broad or opinion-based? All it will do is focus your attention on details that might be related to that question. These details are analogous to puzzle pieces that you place one-by-one into a solution of your underlying, motivating question. One day an answer to that motivating question may appear in the arrangement of those pieces.